# asp net updating gridview row

Tags: asp.net, .net, gridview

i am trying to update the gridview row but i keep getting the duplicate exception error. i am using c#. i am using 3-tier architecture. i am able to insert records, but unable to update record. 
please help thanks

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView3" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AutoGenerateEditButton="True" OnRowEditing="EditRecord" OnRowUpdating="UpdateRecord" DataKeyName = "payClaimId">
<Columns>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Duty ID">
<ItemTemplate><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "dutyId")%></ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Pay Claim ID">
<ItemTemplate><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "payClaimId")%></ItemTemplate>
<EditItemTemplate><asp:TextBox ID="txtpayclaimid" runat="Server" ReadOnly ="true" Text ='<%# Eval("payClaimId") %>'></asp:TextBox></EditItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Date Submitted">
<ItemTemplate><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "printeddate", "{0:d}")%></ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Date Worked">
<ItemTemplate><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "dateWorked", "{0:d}")%></ItemTemplate>
<EditItemTemplate><asp:TextBox ID="txtdateworked" runat="Server" Text ='<%# Eval("dateWorked", "{0:d}") %>'></asp:TextBox></EditItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Total Hours">
<ItemTemplate><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "totalHours")%></ItemTemplate>
<EditItemTemplate><asp:TextBox ID="txttotalhours" runat="Server" Text ='<%# Eval("totalHours") %>'></asp:TextBox></EditItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Status">
<ItemTemplate><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "status")%></ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>

</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
 private void loaddata()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        Timesheet ts = new Timesheet();
        dt = ts.gettimesheetrecords(Convert.ToInt32(txtboxeid.Text));
        GridView3.DataSource = dt;
        GridView3.DataBind();
    }

    protected void EditRecord(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
    {

        GridView3.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;

        loaddata();

    }
    protected void UpdateRecord(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
        GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)GridView3.Rows[e.RowIndex];
        TextBox pcid = (TextBox)row.FindControl("txtpayclaimid");
        TextBox dworked = (TextBox)row.FindControl("txtdateworked");
        TextBox tHours = (TextBox)row.FindControl("txttotalhours");
        int payClaimId = int.Parse(pcid.Text);
        string dateWorked = Convert.ToString(dworked.Text);
        double totalHours = double.Parse(tHours.Text);
        int res = 0;
        PayClaim pc = new PayClaim();


        try
        {
            res = pc.updatepayclaim(payClaimId, dateWorked, totalHours);
            if (res > 0)
            {
                statuslabel.Text = "Record saved";
                GridView3.EditIndex = -1;

                loaddata();
            }
            else
            {
                statuslabel.Text = "Duplicates";
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            statuslabel.Text = "Error";
        }
        finally
        {
            pc = null;
        }
    }
```

my insert payclaim method

```
public int updatepayclaim(int payClaimId, string dateWorked, double totalHours)
    {

        dbCon = new OleDbConnection(sConnection);

        dbCon.Open();
        OleDbCommand com = dbCon.CreateCommand();
        com.CommandText = "Update PayClaim Set totalHours=?, dateWorked=? where payClaimId=?";
        try
        {
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("payClaimId", payClaimId);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("dateWorked", dateWorked);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("totalHours", totalHours);
            return com.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch
        {
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            com.Dispose();
            dbCon.Close();
            dbCon.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

Comment: You're getting an error or `statuslabel.Text = "Duplicates";` executes?

Comment: i am getting the statuslabel.text = duplicates exception when running.

Answer (score 0):

I think in order to answer your question you will need to show the code for the PayClaim updatepayclaim method.

From your description I assume you are getting an Exception and not just a return code greater than 0 (res > 0) and setting of a label to Duplicates - because if you get an exception by the code shown your status label would be 'Error.'

Please clarify.

Comment: i am getting the statuslabel.text = duplicates exception when running, i updated my payclaim method, when i set the breakpoint, i can see the values passed through, but i dont know why the data isnt updated in the database.... thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's the correct syntax. I would try something like this:

```
com.CommandText = "Update PayClaim Set totalHours='@pTotalHours', dateWorked='@pDateWorked' where payClaimId='@pPayClaimId'";
try
{
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pPayClaimId", payClaimId);
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pDateWorked", dateWorked);
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pTotalHours", totalHours);
    return com.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

I would also be curious to know the value of `res`, if it is -1 for error or 0 for no rows updated (you would have initialize it to a non-zero, like -2, to be sure about the latter).

Comment: thanks, but i followed your suggestions, but still unable to update. i changed the int res = -2... or is there a better way to call the method from the code behind? or did i declare my method wrongly? thanks

Comment: What's the value of res when you're debugging? I'll update the code to wrap the parameters in quotes, maybe that's the problem.